# Read/Compile vb.net code dynamically from text file

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to read and compile code from a text file. I have done some of its portion but feeling difficulties when trying to add controls to the Form. Kindly guide me. I am attaching code.

```
Public Class Form1

    Sub Execute()

        ' Creates object of the compiler
        Dim objCodeCompiler As System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler = New VBCodeProvider().CreateCompiler

        'References/Parameters.
        Dim objCompilerParameters As New System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters()

        objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")
        objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll")
        objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll")


        'Compiles in memory.
        objCompilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = True

        'Runs the source code.
        'You can use resources, textbox's or even the settings, up to you! :D
        'Dim strCode As String = TextBox1.Text

        'Compiler Results
        'Dim objCompileResults As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults = objCodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(objCompilerParameters, strCode)

        Dim objCompileResults As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults = objCodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFile(objCompilerParameters, "H:\VB project\LE21 - CodeDom - Run code from Textbox\LE21 - CodeDom - Run code from Textbox\LE21 - CodeDom - Run code from Textbox\file.txt")

        'If an Error occurs
        If objCompileResults.Errors.HasErrors Then
            MsgBox("Error: Line>" & objCompileResults.Errors(0).Line.ToString & ", " & objCompileResults.Errors(0).ErrorText)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Creates assembly
        Dim objAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = objCompileResults.CompiledAssembly

        Dim objTheClass As Object = objAssembly.CreateInstance("MainClass")
        If objTheClass Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Can't load class...")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Trys to excute
        Try
            objTheClass.GetType.InvokeMember("ExecuteCode",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, objTheClass, Nothing)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error:" & ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'Runs the source code from textbox1.
        Execute()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim p As New Form2
        p.Text = "hahahahah"
        p.Show()


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: did you have a question? is there an error? what doesnt work?  "guide me" isnt very specific

Comment: I don't think Visual Studio supports that.

Comment: When I try to make form "Dim p As New Form2
                         p.Show()"    AND ERROR OCCURRED "Type Form2 is not defined "

Comment: But simple code is running. I have already tried hello word.

Comment: `H:...file.txt` needs to contain valid VB code

Comment: @Plutonix It has the valid code but when I try to write code for form controls in file.txt then getting such errors. It is working good with helloo word and some mathematical formulas

Answer (score 0):

> "Type Form2 is not defined"

That's because you haven't defined it.  You may be dynamically loading and compiling some file which contains code which does define it.  But the compiler has no way of knowing that *at compile time*.  Being a statically typed system, the compiler needs to know about all of the types you're using when it compiles the code.

If you're dynamically loading class definitions from a file, then you also need to dynamically invoke those class definitions.  That's going to involve a lot of [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) and [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) and whatnot.  It's not going to be pretty, and it's *definitely* not going to have compile-time type checking.  (And it's going to be very "stringly typed" in the sense that instead of creating an instance of `Form2` you're going to be requesting from reflection to create an instance of `"Form2"` and hoping for the best.)  So you're going to want to put in a lot of error handling for things like, for example, classes which don't exist.

Comment: I am sorry sir, actually I'm new to .net. I did not get your point, did you mean it is bad way to handle code dynamically in this way?

Comment: @RanaTariq: In pretty much 99.9% of cases, yes.  There are *many* considerations to be made, including security and potential for drastic errors.  This approach really shouldn't be taken unless you *really* know a lot about the inner workings of .NET.  (I consider myself a seasoned expert in these things and personally I would avoid doing this at any cost.)  If you're new to .NET, why exactly are you trying to do this in the first place?  Why aren't you just writing a standard application?  What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I need to make simple physics equation editor and solver. I am trying to put the facility of adding new equations to the system. And when user add new equation then the code for its textboxes (variables) should be written automatically and some other logic related to that particular equation.

Comment: @RanaTariq: As you mentioned in a previous comment you "got this to work" with "hello world".  So perhaps go back to that success and see if you can build upon it.  Creating classes clearly isn't going to work (not without a good bit of overhead from the links in my answer), but supposedly you were able to execute entirely procedural code successfully?  If that's the case then perhaps the input files just need to be procedural code without classes?  And as you get more accustomed to how this all fits together you can investigate adding such functionality over time.